Creation of a Ubuntu-based Server providing PXE and HTTPBoot functionality
I am working on an ongoing project which involves having a Server providing PXE and HTTP boot functionality for the install of various Operating Systems
Unfortunately i cannot go into a massive amount of detail but a basic setup would involve multiple client computers on the same network, where a Windows-based DHCP server is running, and the Netboot server snooping for PXE/HTTP boot packets on said network when enabled
The desired outcome would be that the server can be scripted in some matter so that a web GUI could allow for dynamic mounting an distribution of OS isos, i.e. Admin uploads Ubuntu-24.04-Desktop.iso to web GUI, and when mount is initiated, the iso is mounted on the server and bootable via a boot menu served via PXE/HTTP, and subsequently installable
Due to the nature of the project, the provided iso file needs to be booted from, as the clients will not have WAN access on the PXE network, so network install ISOs aren't applicable in this scenario
So far I have been able to create a PXE and HTTP server, which can serve a syslinux, GRUB or iPXE boot menu with varying success, along with isc-dhcp-server doing the PXE snooping, HTTP snooping didn't work in my testing so any http booting was manually pointing the client to the boot file on the http server
GRUB didn't have a massive amount of success, as I couldn't get http booting to function
syslinux had more success, but still not perfect
iPXE is probably going to be my goto but with support from you guys, i can switch between them
Thats about as far as i could get, when i would, for example, boot to the Ubuntu-24.04 contents using vmlinuz and initrd, I would encounter various issues, mostly boiling down to not being able to find a live filesystem with a Casper-Premount error, not being able to mount the live filesystem to somewhere like /dev/ram0 or not being able to finish the boot dropping me to a busybox shell
Booting windows is something i had no success with, i was trying both memdisk methods and wimboot methods, mostly just unable to locate file errors
Not sure where i have been going wrong, it seems that I have basically made the initial part of the servers, but not configured something correctly, as if the client PC can find the PXE/HTTP Server, boot the specified file (iPXE.efi/syslinux.efi/grubx64.efi), and allow the client PC to select an OS, but then when an option is booted, files are loaded from the server, but then not loadable from the client
All help is appreciated and I will give any suggestions I havent tried a go
